# how to split a multiple array, to insert different tables in laravel

Tags: arrays, laravel

I have two array within a array.How to seperate the array into 2 different array in where color and size array will be in two differnt array .

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly:

```php
$table2 = $parameters->get('color');
$table3 = $parameters->get('rank');

$parameters->remove('color');
$parameters->remove('rank');

$table1 = $parameters->all();
```